# Include placeholder in API base path .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, url-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

Wondering how you would go about including a placeholder/variable in the API base path, you would see something like this used in azure devops for example: `https://dev.azure.com/{company-name}/`.
How would you set up your API to have context of the start of the base path.

What I would like to achieve is to let my API have context of which account the API calls are executed in without it having to be part of the API request body. The format of my API would be `https://some-company.com/{account}/_apis/some-api/controller/`.

Comment: can't you just update the pattern with pattern? to receive account as part of api end points? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: traditionally yes but we are moving towards API-Gateway routing in kubernetes and decided to move over to Microsoft's API convention, the API thus only starts getting context of the route from its own base path, which is "some-api" and that is beyond the API routing pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it the suggested way, routing parameters only apply for the route of your controller.

But you could try to extract the information from the current context:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

Comment: I thought as much, this was my initial solution, using regex to extract the account information, hoped that there would be another solution. Thanks, appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at attribute routing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ar):

It's flexible so you can formulate your routes with "attributes" and assign it above the controller/action.

```
[Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]
public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersByCustomer(int customerId) { ... }
```

Comment: I completely agree with you, this is the traditional convention and I have used it to achieve normal restful conventions. In my instance it won't work because of where the API base path starts: `https://some-company.com/{account}/_apis/**api-base-path**/controller/route` and the account information would be before that